# sas how to use a list to store count distinct of all the variables in a table

Tags: list, macros, count, sas, distinct

I want to store the count distinct of each variable from a table in another. I wanted to use a loop for it, over the list of the variables. So first, I stored the variables names in "vars", doing this:

```
proc sql ;
 select name
 into :vars separated by ' ' 
 from dictionary.columns
 where libname eq 'HW' and
 memname eq "ORDERS";
quit;
```

Then, I created another list with the result of the count distinct with the following code:

```
%macro g();
%let b=;
%do i = 1 %to 3;
%let a=%scan(&vars,&i);
    proc sql;
    select count(distinct &a) 
    into :gaby from hw.ORDERS;
    quit;
    %let b=&b &gaby;
%end;
%put &b;
%mend g;

%g();
```

After this, I wanted to add both to a table, but I can add the vars variable but not the b variable.

```
data a;
call symput('lista', symget('vars'));
call symput('lista1', symget('b'));
do i=1 to 3;
    timept=i; 
    variable=scan("&vars",i); 
    dist=scan("&b",i); 
output; 
end;
run;
```

The table shows correctly the name of the variables but instead of showing the count distinct (that were stored in b) shows the letter "b".

Is there a way to perform this? also, is there a way to perform it easily?

Thanks!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close.  I would just use a single SQL pass and create an output table directly.  If you want it in a column form, then use `PROC TRANSPOSE`.

```
proc sql noprint;
select name
 into :vars separated by ' ' 
 from dictionary.columns
 where libname eq 'SASHELP' and
 memname eq "SHOES";
quit;

%put &vars;

%macro create_table();
proc sql noprint;
%local i n var;
%let n = %sysfunc(countw(&vars));

create table output as
select
%do i=1 %to %eval(&n-1);
    %let var = %scan(&vars,&i);
    count(distinct &var) as &var,
%end;
    %let var = %scan(&vars,&n);
    count(distinct &var) as &var
from sashelp.shoes;
quit;
%mend;

%create_table;

proc transpose data=output out=want(rename=(_NAME_=variable COL1=Dist));
run;
```